# Using delegates in apple watch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-3

I don't know why it's crashing when I am trying to create an object of Controller.

```
func pushScreen() {
        var context = SelectModeInterfaceController()
        context.delegate = self
        pushController(withName: "SelectModeInterface", context: nil)    
}
```

I have two screens A and B. I want to send some data from A to B and B to A. It's pretty simple to send the data from A to B using context while B to A seems something different. I have knowledge about how to use delegates in iOS but in watchKit it seems different. If anybody has come up with the solution please share.

Answer (score 0):

I create an singleton class which is just for the purpose of data sharing.  Send the instance of this class, say created in A, to B using context. Updates that B makes will remain after B is dismissed.